# Firebase fetchSignInMethodsForEmail returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to fetch data from firebase in order to know if my user already has an account. Found this [fetchSignInMethodsForEmail](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#fetchsigninmethodsforemail).

The issue is this one:

[image]

The "i" property returns undefined, but after it shows the value "password". When I try to fetch, I only get undefined.

Here's the method I am using:

```
readUser = (user) => {
        user = firebase.auth().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(this.state.email);
    
        
        console.log(user);
        console.log(user.i);
        
       
    }
```

it returns undefined for `console.log(user.i);`, but I need it to return the value "password" or the array length.

Answer (score 5):

`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` returns promise so you need to call it e.g. awaited in async function:

```
readUser = async (user) => {
    user = await firebase.auth().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(this.state.email);

    console.log(user);
    console.log(user.i);
}
```